# Obtener nombre con valor mas alto de una consulta de Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día. 
Tengo una tabla en Sql Server que contiene `Id`, `Nombre`, `Numero`. Los nombres se pueden repetir pero cada uno tendrá un `id` único, necesito obtener los nombres que tengan el numero (`Phone`) mayor.

Adjunto imágenes para que sea mas claro. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto es lo que necesito 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito que sea mayor es la columna `Phone` y que se muestren las tres columnas.

Así me funciona, pero no me gusta nada la idea de comparar por el nombre.

```
SELECT C.ShipperId, C.Shippername, C.Phone
FROM (
  SELECT MAX(A.Phone) AS Phone, A.shippername
  FROM table A
  GROUP BY A.shippername) B
JOIN table C
ON B.phone = C.phone
and B.shippername = C.shippername
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El "window function" `row_number()` está precisamente diseñado para este tipo de situaciones:

```
select t.ShipperID, t.ShipperName, t.Phone
  from (select t.*,
               row_number() over (partition by t.ShipperName order by t.Phone desc) as rn
          from tbl t) t
 where t.rn = 1
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta yo buscaba lo mismo gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puedes obtener los Ids más altos con la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Tabla
ORDER BY ShipperId DESC
```

Con esto, el resultado se ordena de mayor a menor y seleccionas los dos registros (o el número de registros deseados) más altos.

**Actualización**

Para tomar como valor máximo el campo `Phone`, el siguiente query puede ser de ayuda:

```
SELECT * FROM Tabla
WHERE Phone = (SELECT MAX(Phone) FROM Tabla)
ORDER BY ShipperId
```

Answer (score 0):

agrupa por ShipperName obteniendo el `max` ShipperID para cada nombre, así:

```
select ShipperName, max(ShipperID)
  from MiTabla
 group by ShipperName
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, lo que necesito que sea mayor es la columna phone y que se muestren las tres columnas.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede realizar de la siguiente forma

```
SELECT * FROM Shipper WHERE (Phone > (SELECT MIN(Phone) FROM Shipper));
```

ahora supongamos que insertes un campo mas

```
insert into shipper values (5,"platano",3);
```

y quieres hallar siempre el mayor, puedes usar el operador `NOT` y el resultado de la operación sera el contrario sino usamos el operador `NOT`

```
SELECT * FROM Shipper WHERE NOT (Phone < (SELECT MAX(Phone) FROM Shipper));
```